# Canvas strokeStyle not reliably changing?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Here's my code. For some reason it draws the lines in mostly grey.

It would appear that some of the lines are being drawn with two stroke styles on top of each other, even though my draw calls don't actually overlap. Some of the lines are white with inner grey. My white lines are thicker than my grey ones so obviously it's drawing two lines. Are canvas draw calls asynchronous or something?

Any idea why?

```
        for (var i=0; i<minor_lanes.length; i++) {
            connect(minor_lanes[i], "#333", 3);
        }

        for (var i=0; i<major_lanes.length; i++) {
            connect(major_lanes[i], "#fff", 4);
        }

        for (var i=0; i<limited_lanes.length; i++) {
            connect(limited_lanes[i], "#FFFF99", 2);
        }

        function connect(id, color, width) {
            if (!id) {
                return;
            }
            ctx.lineWidth = width;
            ctx.strokeStyle = color;
            $('#' + id).each(function() {
            var laneX = parseInt($(this).css('left')) + $(this).width()/2;
            var laneY = parseInt($(this).css('top')) + $(this).height()/2;
            ctx.moveTo(x,y);
            ctx.lineTo(laneX, laneY);
            ctx.stroke();
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you forget

```
ctx.beginPath();
// draw path
// stroke
ctx.closePath();
```

Comment: And that did it. So I was just building up a single path of lines. The documentation on canvas drawing is frustratingly sparse. Thanks for the help.

Comment: "Frustratingly sparse" if you don't know [this page.](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html)  Also, only `beginPath()` actually affects what the current path is-- `closePath()` basically adds a `lineTo()` to the start of the last subpath and then starts a new subpath at that point.

Comment: Doesn't `ctx.closePath()` implicitly call `ctx.stroke()`?

Answer (score 0):

**Important remark:**

Always put style (fillStyle, strikeStyle, ..) **before** drawing (fillRect, strokeRect, ..)