# HTML Canvas Lines Multiple Colours

Tags: html, canvas, colors, line

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(10, 10);
 for (var i=1; i<=6; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(110*i, 300*1);
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(70, 144, 249, 0.1)';
    ctx.stroke();
        
    ctx.moveTo(10, 10);
        
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Hi, I have two problems.

1 - When I have opacity in my lines the lines seem to always get replicated on top of them leaving the first with multiple opacity and last with only 1 layer of the opacity I set.

2 - I don't seem to be able to have lines with different colours. Because again even when I apply the second colour it goes on top of every line...

Can you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Canvas strokeStyle not reliably changing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683662/canvas-strokestyle-not-reliably-changing)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you begin the path outside the loop. The first line is drawn 6 times while the last is drawn only once. Moving the `beginPath`and the `moveTo` inside the loop solves your problem.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(10, 10);
  ctx.lineTo(110 * i, 300 * 1);
  ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(70, 144, 249, 0.1)";
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.moveTo(10, 10);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```